# Creating a 2 ways ssl handshake (TLS) using GRPC in android client

Tags: java, android, ssl, grpc, grpc-java

I have a python server running using grpc generated from a proto file I created.
The server is using a 2 way ssl authentication, when im running a client from a python file, and entering the server self signed certificate, client certificate and client key, it connects correctly, however im trying to achive this in my android application as well, I tried using sslcontext builder for that, and refrencing the 3 items I stated above (2 certificates and 1 key) that are in my "raw" directory, but it cant seem to recognize them.

```java
 private static SslContext buildSslContext(String trustFile, String clientCertFile, String clientKeyFile) throws SSLException {
        return GrpcSslContexts.forClient()
                .trustManager(new File(trustFile))
                .keyManager(new File(clientCertFile), new File(clientKeyFile))
                .build();
    }
mChannel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("MyServer", 5051).negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS).sslContext(buildSslContext("server.pem","client.pem","key.pem")).build();
```

and I get this error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates: server.pem"

Comment: I have read about adding the certificate to the keystore, would that help?

Comment: Is this the same problem as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6412 ?

Comment: tell us more about 'server.pem' how you made it for example